# Receiving "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range." when trying to execute stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I am trying to run a sql stored procedure in java that updates an admin's information based on an input "AReg_ID." Currently when I run the code I run into this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:228)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1138)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1683)
    at update_admin.main(update_admin.java:21)
```

Here is the stored procedure made in MSSQL:

```
CREATE Procedure UpdateAdmin
@Adm_Fname varchar(255),
@Adm_Lname varchar(255),
@Adm_Address varchar(255),
@Adm_Email varchar(255),
@Adm_Phone varchar(255),
@AReg_ID int

AS

UPDATE Admin
SET Adm_Fname = @Adm_FName, Adm_LName = @Adm_LName, Adm_Address = @Adm_Address, Adm_Email = @Adm_Email, Adm_Phone = @Adm_Phone
FROM Admin A
INNER JOIN Admin_Registration_Form ARF
    ON ARF.Adm_ID=A.Adm_ID
WHERE ARF.AReg_ID= @AReg_ID/* Reg_ID value for the admin being updated*/
```

Here is the java code trying to run the procedure:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class update_admin {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        String connectionURL=
                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                        +"database=test_2;"
                        +"user=user;"
                        +"password=password;";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

            CallableStatement stmtadm= conn.prepareCall("{CALL UpdateAdmin('Adm_Fname','Adm_Lname', 'Adm_Address','Adm_Email','Adm_Phone','AReg_ID')}");

            stmtadm.setString(1, "First Name");
            stmtadm.setString(2, "Last Name");
            stmtadm.setString(3, "1324 Address Street");
            stmtadm.setString(4, "admin@admin.com");
            stmtadm.setString(5,"123-456-789");
            stmtadm.setInt(6,4 );

        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("unable to make connection with db");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `'Adm_Fname'` (etc) are string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you update

```
CallableStatement stmtadm= conn.prepareCall("{CALL UpdateAdmin('Adm_Fname','Adm_Lname', 'Adm_Address','Adm_Email','Adm_Phone','AReg_ID')}");
```

to

```
CallableStatement stmtadm= conn.prepareCall("CALL UpdateAdmin(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

and see if it working or not?

Comment: I feel silly for missing this, thank you very much!

Comment: Happens to everyone :). Can you please update it as answer if it worked?